# libphonenumber php cannot find base class Locale

Tags: php, locale, libphonenumber

I am using the php implmentation of libphonenumber from

```
giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php
```

I need it to just do a basic sense and validity check on a phone number entered by a users.

I have taken the whole `src/libphonenumber` directory and its sub directories and copied it into my project.  I do not use Composer and, as this is only one element of my project, am hoping not to have to climb that particular learning curve just now.  I put the following simple autoloader at the start of the script.

```
namespace libphonenumber;

spl_autoload_register('libphonenumber\myAutoloader');

function myAutoloader($className)
{
$path = 'libphonenumber/';
$parts=explode('\\',$className,2);
$filename=str_replace('\\','/',$parts[1]);

include $path.$filename.'.php';
}
```

The auto loader works fine except for when it comes to include the file `geocoding/Locale.php` which includes a single class 'Locale' as follows;

```
class Locale extends \Locale
```

The error I get is

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Locale' not found in /var/www/luthor/php/libphonenumber/geocoding/Locale.php on line 6
```

I am pretty new to namespaces and oo in php.  I understand that Locale is a php class.  My question is **Why is it not found**

Comment: I see you have already solved this, but thought I best comment:

The package requires the php 'intl' extension, which is listed in the requirements when installed via Composer. I will make sure that it is listed clearly in the README for those not using Composer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  The use of Locale requires the international extension for php to be installed see the following question

[Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found with ZF2 beta5 skeleton application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509204)